# ¿Cómo puedo calcular los 15 primeros factoriales de Fibonacci?

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

Hola estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que tengo que calcular los 15 primeros factoriales de fibonacci. Yo he realizado una primera función donde calculo el e-nesimo término de la serie de fibonacci y después otra función para calcular el fibonorial.

Esta última no me sale, busqué la formula para calcular el factorial del la serie de fibonacci y encontré ésta `fibonor(0)=1;  fibonor(n+1) = fibonor(n)* fibo(n+1)`, pero no se como implementarlo.

```
function fibo (n)
{
    let a = 0;
    let b = 1;

    for (let k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {   
        let c;
        c = b + a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        console.log(a);  
    }
    return a;
};

function fibonor (n){

    if(n == 0){ return 1;}
    else{ return

    fibo(n)*fibonor(n-1);
}};

let factorfibo = 15;
console.log( "Los 15 primeros factoriales de fibonacci son:"+ fibonor (factorfibo));
```

Un saludo.

Comment: fijate que en el return llamas a fibo en vez de fibonor, y que, para que n llegue a 0, debe ir decrementando y no incrementando.

Comment: Lo he modificado pero me sigue sin salir..., es así como me dices?

Comment: Estoy en un móvil y no puedo comprobar, creo que n*fibonor(n-1)

Comment: Mejor espera a alguien con ordenador, creo que no entendí bien el problema.

Comment: Creo que debes definir qué es un *factorial de Fibonacci*. ¿Acaso se refiere al factorial del enésimo elemento de la sucesión de Fibonacci?. Si este fuera el caso, te enfrentas al problema de la representación numérica. El máximo valor factorial que se puede representar en Javascript es 21!. Si tomamos en cuenta que el valor del octavo elemento de la sucesión es precisamente 21, no podrás representar el elemento número 15. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** He olvidado colocar algunas validaciones para `n < 3` en la función `fibonacci`. Así que las anexo y también dejo la versión recursiva:

```javascript
function fibonacci(n) {
  return n <= 0 ? 0 : n <= 2 ? 1 : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Tomando en cuenta las limitaciones de representación que ha mencionado @mauricio-contreras y que las observaciones que ha mencionado son correctas sobre si *factorial de Fibinacci* se refiere al factorial del enésimo elemento de la sucesión de Fibonacci. Entonces tu código sería algo así:

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
  const series = Array(n+1);
  series[0] = 0;

  if (n <= 0) {
    return series;
  }

  series.fill(1, 1);

  if (n < 3) {
    return series.slice(0, n + 1);
  }

  for (let i = 3; i < n+1; i++) {
    series[i] = series[i-1] + series[i-2];
  }

  return series;
}

function factorial(n) {
  return n === 0 ? 1 : n * factorial (n - 1);
}

const serieFibonacci = fibonacci(15);

for (let i = 0; i < serieFibonacci.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Factorial de ${serieFibonacci[i]}: ${factorial(serieFibonacci[i])}`);
}
```

Nota que después del factorial de 21, los números son representados en notación científica y depués como infinito puesto que ya es imposible representarlos de forma exacta.

El código está basado en los algoritmos explicados [aquí](http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica3/basico/recursiva/recursiva.html).

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has aclarado mucho. Si se refiere al factorial del enésimo elemento de la sucesión de Fibonacci.